# How can I limit GPU usage for every process?

Tags: nvidia, gpu, resource-limiting, ethereum

I'm trying to switch over back to Linux *(as my primary OS at least)* and one thing that's annoying now is mining etherium.
On Windows even with 99% GPU usage everything runs perfectly fine and I can still watch YouTube and work on things without taking much of a performance hit but on vanilla Ubuntu the entire PC starts lagging and eventually freezes to a point of no return.

Is there any way I could limit the maximum GPU usage for every process?
(I'm mining using Salad.io which is still in beta for Linux but it's basically just a wrapper for PhoenixMiner)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm renice , or setting to very low priority from system monitor works to an extent. If you open

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes

you can see animations are smooth. However, sluggishness takes a couple of seconds to get rid of. You can take your UI and window manager to higher priorities ...